# How to add a web view to Jira dashboard

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

We use Jira.. like many others.. but we also use a forum for our business discussions board and have been since before Jira existed, so we have a lot of historical information in there.

It is possible to add "Gadgets" to the dashboard, but is it possible to add a webview somewhere?

Comment: what do you mean "web view"? gadget is a type of web view in this situation?

Comment: ah ok, so I could write a gadget that was basically an iframe to another website... which in this case would be our forum url?

Comment: I don't understand your question, have you ever write a gadget?

Comment: I have not, i had a look around the gadgets but I couldn't see a basic iframe style one. So you're saying this is fairly std stuff for a jira gadget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this guide:
https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-platform/guides/dashboards/tutorial-writing-gadgets-for-jira

Open src/main/resources/gadget.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Module>
    <ModulePrefs title="__MSG_gadget.title__" directory_title="__MSG_gadget.title__"
        description="__MSG_gadget.description__">
        <Optional feature="gadget-directory">
            <Param name="categories">
                JIRA
            </Param>
        </Optional>
        <Optional feature="atlassian.util" />
        <Optional feature="auth-refresh" />
        <Require feature="views" />
        <Require feature="settitle"/>
        <Require feature="oauthpopup" />
        #oauth
        <Locale messages="__ATLASSIAN_BASE_URL__/download/resources/jira-gadget-tutorial-plugin/i18n/ALL_ALL.xml"/>
    </ModulePrefs>
    <Content type="html" view="profile">
        <!-- omitted for now -->
    </Content>
 </Module>
```

Did you see:

```
   <Content type="html" view="profile">
        <!-- omitted for now -->
    </Content>
```

Just insert your frame here:

```
   <Content type="html" view="profile">
        <iframe src="your forum url">
    </Content>
```